# Process events even if DirectX9 Game Window is minimized - Hooking, Remote App

Tags: c++, event-handling, mouseevent, hook, keyboard-events

I have an opensource (VC++/VS2010) project base which I am testing for the last few days. I can hook (using [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/)) a DirectX9 Game on the server, then send off the captured screen buffer to the client. The client views the game as a video.  As you may know Cloud Gaming is the norm.
But I have stumbled into a serious issue.
When I am playing the game at the client, all is ok, all events captured at the client (mouse/kb) are sent back to the server and the server replays them, fine! - I can see from the logs that events are correctly reaching the server. but as soon as the game window is minimized at the server, all goes crazy.
The logs show me the mouse and KB events are reaching the server, but since them game window is minimized, the game is not reacting to my clicks. Putting it simple

1) Server is a dll that Hooks into the Game exe.
2) Once hooked, client can connect to the server, client events are relayed to the server, server sends the events down into the game. Game play fine!
3) When I minimized the game window - whatever I do the game wont react. I still see the game window visible on the client end.

Does this mean Windows7 (64bit) is basically "EATING" away the events before they the server can relay them to the game? Or just because the game is minimized, the mouse and kb events have been taken over by windows while the server is accepting the events.

SendInput(...) Windos API function is called to replay events at the Server which is basically sending the events to the hooked game window (SetWindowsHookEx) when it receives the client input from the network.

Comment: When a window is minimized, the application lose the display device, and directx can't draw anything. That doesn't mean the application is not reacting to events. Are you sure there is no reaction ? It is also likely (and legitimate) that the game is ignoring events when the window is minimized.

Comment: @ElderBug I am suspecting the same. I think the game is basically ignoring the events all together. Makes sense as in normal mode - the game would not respond to KB/Mouse events since the window is minimized.  But! the mouse seems to move around on the server screen when actually it is being moved at the client. So therefore I would have expected the hooks to redirect the KB/Mouse events to the game. But this turns out no to be the case so far.

Comment: Since the mouse is mostly handled by the OS, I think it's reasonable to assume the mouse will work independently of the game state.

Comment: Yeah - I think so. That is why I can still see the mouse.